# Glyphicon font not loading in IE but works fine in chrome

Tags: user-interface, web, fonts

We are using glyphicon fonts in our project and the bootstrap-min.css seem not loading on IE because of which fonts are not appearing but it works fine on chrome.

Also if instead of pointing the bootstrap min.css from local if I point it to cdn then it starts working on IE as well.

Can somebody please suggest the reason behind it as we don't want to use cdn?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? (And the problem is probably related to the same-origin policy.)

Comment: can u please elaborate more?